# Get checked value in checkbox and put in a list

Tags: javascript, html

consider the following code:

```
<p>Select letter: </p>

<input id="check type="checkbox" value="A"> A <br>
<input id="check type="checkbox" value="B"> B <br>
<input id="check type="checkbox" value="C"> C <br>
<input id="check type="checkbox" value="D"> D <br>
<input id="check type="checkbox" value="E"> E <br>
<input id="check type="checkbox" value="F"> F <br>
<input id="check type="checkbox" value="G"> G <br>

<div id="list">

</div>
```

Supposed that I only checked the letters A, C , E and G.

How can I put it in the #list in an unordered list using JavaScript like this:

- A
- C
- E
- G

Edit:

Thank you for commenting that I need to first attempt to solve the question I have. I try to make my question as short as possible as to not waste your time. but in case you want to know how I am doing before solving this. This is what I did.

```
//HTML       
<input class="messageCheckbox" onclick="changeInclusions()" type="checkbox" value="A"> A<br>
       <input class="messageCheckbox" onclick="changeInclusions()" type="checkbox" value=" B"> B <br>
       <input class="messageCheckbox" onclick="changeInclusions()" type="checkbox" value="C">C <br>
      <input class="messageCheckbox" onclick="changeInclusions()" type="checkbox" value="D" > D <br>
      <input class="messageCheckbox" onclick="changeInclusions()" type="checkbox" value="E" checked> E



     //JS   
document.getElementByclass('messageCheckbox').addEventListener('change', changeletter);

        function changeletter() {
          let checkedValue = document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked').value;
          document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = checkedValue  ;
        }
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Hello Sruthi , I edited my question. Please reconsider. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, update unordered list everytime a checkbox changes

```js
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("#check"), n => n.addEventListener("change", updateList))

function updateList() {
  const list = document.querySelector("#list");
  while (list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll("#check:checked");
  [].map.call(checked, (n) => {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = n.value;
    list.appendChild(li);
  })
}
```

```html
<p>Select letter: </p>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value="A"> A <br>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value="B"> B <br>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value="C"> C <br>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value="D"> D <br>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value="E"> E <br>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value="F"> F <br>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value="G"> G <br>
<div id="list">

</div>
```

Comment: Hello, your code works. but now I need to add an id to the inputs likes this.

<p>Select letter: </p>
                    <input id="check" type="checkbox" value="A"> A <br>
                    <input id="check" type="checkbox" value="B"> B <br>

Comment: you want all of them to have id="check"? id should be unique, or do you want class="check" on them

Comment: yes, all of them have id="check"

Comment: ok i edited my answer so they have id="check"

Comment: Okay, Thank you! Now I understand. I tried editing your code and use document.getElementById  but All I need to do is change #check. Thank you.

Comment: if you change it to getElementById it probably wont work because it only selects the first element with id="check"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do like this?

```js
$('.myckeck').on('change', function () {
    if(this.checked==true){
       $('#list').append('<li id='+$(this).val()+'>'+$(this).val()+'</li>');
    }else{
       $('#'+$(this).val()).remove();  
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<p>Select letter: </p>

<input type="checkbox" value="A" class="myckeck"> A <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="B" class="myckeck"> B <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="C" class="myckeck"> C <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="D" class="myckeck"> D <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="E" class="myckeck"> E <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="F" class="myckeck"> F <br>
<input type="checkbox" value="G" class="myckeck"> G <br>

<div>
    <ul id="list">       
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This also works. Thank you very much!

Comment: you are welcome dear